# What does !grep do in perl?

Tags: perl, grep

```
print !grep { 3 == $_ } 2, 3, 8;
```

And i get nothing.

I've seen this used.

```
if (!grep { /^#EXTINF:/ } @lines)
```

To make it worse it's hard to search for !grep on Google or Duckduckgo because the search doesn't search for !. And all i could find was a few bits of code in Perldocs.

Comment: Hint: `!` -->  "not".  Now, just search for "perl grep".  Or better yet, `perldoc -f grep`.  :P

Comment: Omg i figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: please answer your own question with what you have found. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

grep returns:

- in array context, an array with the elements that makes true the condition (`3 == $_`)
- in scalar context, the number of elements of the array that grep has filtered

Also, `!` is a perl negation, so if you have a true value (like 1), it transform to a false value

Unrolling your code:

```
my $a = grep { 3 == $_ } 2, 3, 8; #<-- $a takes 1 (only one element satisfies the condition)
print ! $a; #<-- prints nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a subtle difference between

```
grep !/foo/, @bar
```

If the array @bar is empty then this test will return nothing. If @bar contains elements, then this test will return the number of non matching elements in scalar context, or an array of matching elements in list context.

and,

```
!grep /foo/, @bar
```

If the array @bar is empty or contains any number of elements non of which match, then this test will return 1 in scalar context. If @bar contains any elements that match, then this test will return nothing.